# mixing ajax and full requests: handle "The Http Transport returned a 0 status code"-error

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

i have two actions in the same form and i am not able to resolve the problem with the suggestions found in similiar topics:

1.

```
<h:commandLink action="#{bean.timeConsumingAction}">
    Create Report
    <f:ajax />
</h:commandLink>
```

2.

```
<h:commandLink action="#{bean.downloadFile}">
  Download some File
</h:commandLink>

public void timeConsumingAction() {         
    //time-consuming business-action     
}

public void downloadFile() {            
  try {
   Faces.sendFile(someFile, true);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }  
}
```

When the user triggers the ajax-request in the first link and then clicks the second link while the ajax-status isn't completed, 
i see this message:

```
httpError: The Http Transport returned a 0 status code.  This is usually the result of mixing ajax and full requests.  This is usually undesired, for both performance and data integrity reasons
```

is there a way to handle this without blocking the UI with javascript? i think about a user-friendly custom message.

i tried with

```
  <f:ajax onerror=""/>
```

but the error-handler will not fire in that case.